# In the absence of predictor X, target Y is non-zero. what does it mean?

Tags: self-study, p-value, interpretation, regression-coefficients

[image: Coefficients and p-values table]

Having this table as a base of analysis that explains linear regression with just one predictor X - TV advertising (in thousands of dollars) and one target variable Y - Sales of a product (in thousands of units) and a quote below from the book "Introduction to Statistical Learning":

> A small p-value for the intercept indicates that we can reject the
>   null hypothesis that β0 = 0, and a small p-value for TV indicates that
>   we can reject the null hypothesis that β1 = 0. Rejecting the latter
>   null hypothesis allows us to conclude that there is a relationship
>   between TV and sales. Rejecting the former allows us to conclude that
>   in the absence of TV expenditure, sales are non-zero

What does it mean that the sales are non-zero?
Does it mean that that if we don't use the TV advertising at all, we will still have sales?
Thanks

Comment: Hint: what are the predicted sales when the value of `TV` is zero?

Comment: This should have the self study tag.

Comment: Product has a base sales level without any advertisement. Advertisement boosts the sales above the base level. That's why when calculating return on marketing investment one should only consider what's above the base level for example (of course there are soft benefits like brand image, etc).

Comment: @whuber Just B0, which is 7.0325 x 1000 units? I think I'm getting it. It's what Cagdas Ozgnec says - just the base sales value of the product without any advertisement at all and it will be still non-zero. Thanks